# VBA - Looping through sub For/If Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble looping through my For statement for this[image: data]

```
Dim c As Range, color As Integer, y As Integer
Sheets("Point Names").Select
numpts = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
y = x
With Sheets("Reporting")
    For y = 1 To numpts
        Set c = Range("C" & (12 * y - 2))
        For color = c To Range(c, Range(c).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count
            If Cells(color).FormulaR1C1 = "=Abs(R[-2]C-R[-1]C)/R[-1]C)" _
            > ToleranceMean * ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) Then
                Cells(color).Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
        Next color
    Next y
End With
```

My goal is to get each cell that lies outside the tolerance mean red in the line, `Change in Temp`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it doing that is in error.  There is no question here.

Comment: What's your issue? I believe, if your data showing starts with `A1` in the top left, your `numpts` will always be `2`. Maybe want to use `A3` as the range to count with?

Comment: I put in a better picture to describe it.  And it just is not looping through it properly.  Plus there is a varying number of groupings like this.  For this specific example there are 10 other groupings like this.

Comment: Please reconsider the `numpts` definition - you're getting number based on blank cells, is that correct? Above you'll get `6`.  Also, have you tried just Conditional Formatting, without VBA? Also, you can step through your code with `F8` to see what it's doing, line by line.  Can you clarify what's not working properly? How isn't it looping correctly?

Comment: It is grabbing `numpts` from `Sheets("Point Names")`.  I have gone through line by line and it seems like it runs through it but nothing comes up.  And This is a tool, so I reset the data regularly.  I am not sure if conditional formatting is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of issues with that code, but probably first thing to fix: You are selecting sheet `"Point Names"` (why do you select it? No need for that), use a with sheets("Reporting") - statement but within the `with` you are not using anything of that `with`. All of your code uses the active sheet which is probably not what you want. You have to write `.cells`and  `.Range` (note the leading dot)